# How to monitor memory utilized on RAM by a java function?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

I have deployed a java application on a server and I am testing it by executing automation test cases. There are multiple test cases that are being executed. Is there a tool or any other way by which I can monitor memory acquired by function on RAM Also is there a way by which I can monitor memory utilized by an individual test case?

Comment: https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki